# Как прервать закачку файла в режиме Streamed?

Tags: c#, wcf

Как прервать на сервере закачку файла (на сервер) в режиме Streamed?
Stream.Dispose() не помогает, сервер всё равно скачивает полностью файл, даже если я не прочитал из потока ни одного байта, и даже если метод получения уже завершился.

Comment: уточнил в вопросе, что прервать закачку нужно на сервере

Comment: уточнил, что файл отправляется с клиента на сервер

Answer (score 0):

Ты можешь уменьшить параметр [`closeTimeout`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh924831(v=vs.110).aspx) и/или указать [`maxBufferSize`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/basichttpbinding) в `app.config`, учти, что `Stream.Dispose` будет бросать `TimeoutException`, если не успеет закрываться за отведённое время. Не забудь его поймать и погасить.

Comment: не подходит способ, т.к. сессию разрывать не надо, а  maxBufferSize уже установлен

Comment: @ИванК Тогда на ум приходит только получить при помощи Reflection сокет и принудительно его закрыть.

Comment: я могу закрыть принудительно канал вызвав его метод Abort(), но это так же завершит и сессию. Хотелось бы корректно отменить передачу файла.

Comment: Тогда разве что отправить серверу команду: горшочек, не вари!

Comment: ну это я могу) но вопрос как раз в том и есть: как сервер прервёт передачу по требованию клиента?

Comment: Стоп, так ведь у тебя на сервере есть какой-то поток или асинхронная задача, которая вычитывает файл с файловой системы и присылает её клиенту, разве нет? Вот и прекрати эту операцию. О.о

Comment: от клиента приходит файл, в виде Stream, сервер отказывается читать из этого потока, и сразу выходит из метода, итог: файл всё равно скачивается в оперативку без моего участия и сразу уничтожается. Вроде ничего такого, но если файл большой, то это загружает сеть надолго.

Comment: кстати, клиент так же не может прекратить отправлять файл, т.к. в режиме Stream всё что от клиента требуется передать этот Stream, а уже считывать байты из этого потока будет принимающая сторона.

Comment: @ИванК не могу объяснить на примере, так как просто не знаю `wcf`, но в любом случае сервер не может вычитывать данные из `FileStream` открытого на стороне клиента и наоборот. Ты открываешь файл на чтение, вычитываешь блок данных в память, записываешь его в `NetworkStream` из которого данные читает сервер (также, блоками) и, например, складывает в `FileStream` на своей стороне. Твоя задача - прервать передачу в одном из этих мест. Если ты просто открываешь поток файла и отдаёшь его API WCF, то либо закрой `FileStream` либо передавай данные вручную, блоками байт, а не целым потоком.